# Is it possible to replace the base Component set for Blazor in abp.io framework to use MudBlazor?

Tags: blazor, abp, mudblazor

Any experience customizing abp.io by using another set of UI components like mudblazor.com, does the framework allows to redefine the UI at this level?

Comment: This is interesting. I wish someone from ABP or ASPNetZero can answer.